# Can I have both a main account and a "smurf" account linked to my Steam account?

Tags: dota-2

1. In League of Legends, some players make "smurf" accounts, which are typically lower-levelled or lower-ranked accounts to play on instead of a main account. Is there a good reason for creating a smurf account in DotA 2?
2. If so, can I have two DotA 2 accounts on one Steam account, or do I have to use a separate Steam account?

Comment: If you have more than one question, create more than one question!

Comment: How is this to broad? Look at the answer... The questions are clearly highly linked to each other, the second one is merely the obvious follow-up to the first one, which itself does have such an obvious answer that is hard to justify as an own question.

Comment: I could see the point if there was actually a multitude of reasons for creating a smurf account, but would still disagree because he's only interested in whether or not there is a reason at all. So the answer would either say "there's not" or "there is". Realistically, there can't be many reasons, so the amount of possible answers is reasonable.

Comment: I think poor wording led to massive down votes. Honestly though, this is not a bad question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can make a smurf account to relive the MMR determination phase of a player. Afterwards, you'd probably go back to what you are in your first account. Another reason can be if you don't want your first account identity to be discovered when you want to play some particular play that are typically frowned upon.
2. You can only have 1 DOTA2 account per Steam account as it is tied to each other. You can make another Steam account, however, to make a smurf account for DOTA2.